# An Error occured while making HTTP Request from POSTMAN

Tags: azure, postman

This Error Occurs While I am trying to make any HTTP request to my REST API on Azure server from POSTMAN.
Why is this occurs ?
[image]

Comment: Connection Refused means that Postman attempted to connect to your server's TCP/IP stack, but there is nobody listening on port 8082 for connections. Since port 8082 is not in a listening state, the connection was refused.

Comment: Is it possible you were using that post locally during development and it switched to 443 (https) when publishing to Azure? Also, try the fully qualified url instead of an IP address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be your machine was started but you forgot to start the Azure server. I once faced the same problem, it occurs because my server was not properly started

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs due to the tcp/ip request. This indicates whether you have not started your virtual machine or you your api needs a token to access